# Stored Proc to insert rows using Joins

Tags: database, oracle, join, plsql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables having IP_Address as common column. My requirement is to get the IP_Address and its associated details in table 1 that are for last 90 days and are not in table 2 and insert the delta in a new table on an nightly basis

DB used: oracle 11g

Table 3 should contain 1 record per IP_Address from Table 1 that are not in Table 2

```
Table 1
--------------------------------------------------
IP_Address    Store_name  source   TRANS_INIT_TIME
--------------------------------------------------
192.168.0.1    abc          e      16-06-29 05:49:16.775265000
192.168.0.1    abc          e      16-07-01 07:44:29.019723000
192.168.0.2    ghi          b      16-07-06 10:53:54.588610000
192.168.0.2    ghi          b      16-07-12 04:04:20.293644000
192.168.0.3    hjg          e      16-07-12 03:54:36.024915000
192.168.0.3    hjg          e      16-07-15 03:46:27.712961000
192.168.0.4    uiu          e      16-09-12 08:57:48.360136000

Table 2
--------------------------
IP.Address    loc    name
--------------------------
192.168.0.2    hjh   uiui

Table 3
--------------------------------
IP_Address  Store_name  source
-------------------------------
```

I have prepared join to get the unique IP_Address from table1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.IP_ADDRESS
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.IP_ADDRESS= T2.IP_ADDRESS
    WHERE T1.TRANS_INIT_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE-90 AND SYSDATE
    AND T2.IP_ADDRESS IS NULL
    AND T1.IP_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL;
```

I am struck here on how to get the first row data for these returns IPs and insert them in table 3 through procedure. can anyone help no this ?

```
Expected Result:

Table 3
    --------------------------------
    IP_Address  Store_name  source
    -------------------------------
    192.168.0.1    abc          e 
    192.168.0.2    ghi          b
    192.168.0.3    hjg          e
    192.168.0.4    uiu          e
```

Comment: Based ONLY on what you wrote in the question, how do you or we determine which row(s) is/are for the last 90 days? I don't see a TRANS_INIT_TIME column in Table 1. Then: if you insert a row in Table 3 now, because it has a date from 70 days ago, will you have to DELETE it from Table 3 after 20 more days? If not, why not?

Comment: Also: What are you comparing between Table 1 and Table 2? It can't be the entire row, since the two tables have different columns (presumably with different type of information); or did you mean to show the same info in Table 1 and Table 2? That's not how it looks now.

Comment: I just added 'TRANS_INIT_TIME' column in table 1. every day I have to delete existing data and insert the new data to table 3 through the job byrunning this proc. The only match between table1, table 2 is IP_address and I am bothered about the columns of table 1. Moreover, there is no relation or constraints on these tables.

Answer (score 0):

In your case is enough  test only the left join key column that is null  (this mean that this key don't match with the key form the main table

and for insert you can use an insert select

```
  INSERT INTO Table3 (IP_ADDRESS, Store_name, source)
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.IP_ADDRESS, min(T1.Store_name), min(T1.Source)
      FROM Table1 T1
      LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
      ON T1.IP_ADDRESS= T2.IP_ADDRESS
      WHERE T1.TRANS_INIT_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE-90 AND SYSDATE
      and AND T2.IP_ADDRESS IS NULL
      group by T1.IP_ADDRESS
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I need the other columns in table 1 as well and I can't get the first record of each unique IP_dress group to insert

Comment: which are the column that you need and i which tables they are ?

Comment: I am looking for columns that are present in table 3 to be extracted from table 1.

Comment: I have update the answer  wiith the column you mention in table3 .. from table1

Comment: I tired this query before, but issue here is I am getting multiple rows for the same IP_address because table 1 has duplicate entries for the same IP_address and my requirement is to get unique ip_address to be inserted in table3.

Comment: You have rows with the same ip_address and different store_name and source?   .. if yes which value you need .. the first?  .. the last? ..

Comment: first row from each IP group is enough. I just updated my expected result for table 3. please have a look

Comment: I have update the answer .. with aggregation function

Comment: thanks for all your help, if I have more columns to be extracted from table 1 to table 3 then should I have to add min() for each column or is there any other alternative approach ?

Comment: If you want one row only for IP_ADDRESS .. you should  apply to all the column you select the  aggregation function (min )  ..

Comment: @Chandu (and @scaisEdge) - what do you both mean by "first" and "last"?  Also, if you use MIN on several columns, the result will have values that may not all be found together in the same row in Table 1, is that OK? (Usually it isn't.)

Comment: @mathguy   . based on the sample provided by OP the query should return  only one row .. but the OP say that he get more than one  (strange) so a way for reduce the rows is using some aggregation function .. this is the reason  for asking if th OP need a specific row or only one from the possible rows ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - My bad; I missed the fact that for a fixed ip address, store_name and source were constant. (One wonders why they are in this table and not in a separate, smaller one.) If the values may be different, then you would have the problem I raised in my comment.

Comment: @mathguy  . i know  .. but is a strange  Question .. is not usual (or could be that the OP show only a part of the data) that the result is not distintc by the distinct clause .. so i give some suggestions and tricks .. could be not completly canonical .. ..

Answer (score 0):

You want the IP_ADDRESS to be unique in the result set but you haven't indicated which row you want for store_name and source.  Just pick one randomly maybe?  I'm not sure which one you want but here are three different ways to get that table3 you want.

Using an aggregate so you can group by IP_ADDRESS and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT T1.IP_ADDRESS, MAX(T1.STORE_NAME) AS STORE_NAME, MAX(T1.SOURCE) AS SOURCE
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM TABLE2 T2
                  WHERE T1.IP_ADDRESS = T2.IP_ADDRESS)
GROUP BY T1.IP_ADDRESS
ORDER BY T1.IP_ADDRESS;
```

Using an aggregate and a left outer join:

```
SELECT T1.IP_ADDRESS, MAX(T1.STORE_NAME) AS STORE_NAME, MAX(T1.SOURCE) AS SOURCE
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.IP_ADDRESS = T2.IP_ADDRESS
WHERE T2.IP_ADDRESS IS NULL
GROUP BY T1.IP_ADDRESS
ORDER BY T1.IP_ADDRESS;
```

Using an analytical function and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT SUB.IP_ADDRESS, SUB.STORE_NAME, SUB.SOURCE
FROM    (
        SELECT T1.IP_ADDRESS, T1.STORE_NAME, T1.SOURCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.IP_ADDRESS) AS ROWNUMBER
        FROM Table1 T1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                          FROM TABLE2 T2
                          WHERE T1.IP_ADDRESS = T2.IP_ADDRESS)
        ) AS SUB
WHERE SUB.ROWNUMBER = 1
ORDER BY SUB.IP_ADDRESS;
```

Comment: Jon, thanks for the reply. The query you shared is not giving me unique records from table 1. I am seeing duplicates. I need unique record from each group of common IP based records to be inserted in table 3

Comment: I just updated my expected result for table 3. please have a look

Comment: I hope my revised answer helps.